# Xcode, very strange SQLite SQL SELECT LIKE issue on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, select

I have made a SQLite application for my iPhone.
When i test my SELECT on my SQLite DB placed on my iMac everything works fine, but when on iPhone i get no rows returned.

```
SELECT ID, SAP_PART_NR, SAP_DESC, MOQ, INC, NLT, DISCOUNT_CODE, AD_EURO, AD_USD, OEM_EURO, OEM_USD FROM Component WHERE SAP_PART_NR LIKE '%AWM423%' LIMIT 200
```

#### Now the strange part

When i use the select below on the iPhone, one record returns with the SAP_PART_NR **AWM42300V**

```
SELECT ID, SAP_PART_NR, SAP_DESC, MOQ, INC, NLT, DISCOUNT_CODE, AD_EURO, AD_USD, OEM_EURO, OEM_USD FROM Component WHERE SAP_PART_NR LIKE '%AWM42%' LIMIT 200
```

Both selects returns a row (as they should), when tested on the iMac

Is it some kind of bug on the iPhone/SQlite ?

i'm not able to figure it out....All my hair has turned grey....:-(

#### Non working code (no rows selected)

```
-(void) searchDB:(NSString *)strSearch {

    NSString *wildcardSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", strSearch];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if(searchSTMT == nil) {
       const char *sql = "SELECT ID, SAP_PART_NR, SAP_DESC, MOQ, INC, NLT, DISCOUNT_CODE, AD_EURO, AD_USD, OEM_EURO, OEM_USD FROM Component WHERE SAP_PART_NR LIKE '%AWM4230%'";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &searchSTMT, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(searchSTMT)) {

        while(sqlite3_step(searchSTMT) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(searchSTMT, 0);
            Database *DatabaseObj = [[Database alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            DatabaseObj.sapPart = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 1)];
            DatabaseObj.sapDesc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 2)];
            DatabaseObj.sapMOQ = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 3)];                
            DatabaseObj.sapINC = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 4)];                 
            DatabaseObj.sapNLT = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 5)];
            DatabaseObj.sapDISCOUNT = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 6)]; 

            DatabaseObj.oemEURO = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 7)];
            DatabaseObj.oemUSD = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 8)];    
            DatabaseObj.adEURO = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 9)];         
            DatabaseObj.adUSD = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchSTMT, 10)];                        

            [appDelegate.compArray addObject:DatabaseObj];
        }
    }
    else 
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while getting the rows. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    //Reset the detail statement.
    sqlite3_reset(searchSTMT);

}
```

#### working code 1 row selected

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {<p>
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt = NULL;

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

       const char *sql = "SELECT ID, SAP_PART_NR, SAP_DESC, MOQ, INC, NLT, DISCOUNT_CODE, AD_EURO, AD_USD, OEM_EURO, OEM_USD FROM Component WHERE SAP_PART_NR LIKE '%AWM4230%'";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                Database *DatabaseObj = [[Database alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                DatabaseObj.sapPart = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                DatabaseObj.sapDesc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
                DatabaseObj.sapMOQ = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];                
                DatabaseObj.sapINC = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)];                 
                DatabaseObj.sapNLT = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];
                DatabaseObj.sapDISCOUNT = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)]; 
                //PRICES
                DatabaseObj.oemEURO = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 7)]; 
                DatabaseObj.oemUSD = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 8)];    
                DatabaseObj.adEURO = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 9)];         
                DatabaseObj.adUSD = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 10)];                      

                [appDelegate.compArray addObject:DatabaseObj];
            }
        }
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.

    sqlite3_reset(selectstmt);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to query the database and iterate through the rows on your iPhone app?

Comment: I would test it with something less complex, such as a literal string. If that works on both iMac and iPhone/iOS, then it's something with the condition.

Comment: I've also had issues with iPhone and casting certain data types on return, so if you can debug the result row count, that might help narrow it down.

Comment: As i tried to explain above, i have already tried to make a literal string with the same result (See first select string).

I'm not sure how/where to debug - when i debug the SQL string everything seems OK, but i'm not able to debug the "compiled select string" ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Very strange.... I tried a few things. If I use the SELECT the first time i open the database, it works fine, but the other one doesn't

Dosen anyone see the difference / problem ?

Comment: For some reason, i think it might be this if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(searchSTMT)) i just can't figure out why..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - look in the comments. I'm still not 100% sure why/how this solved it though..